# Select statement to get one record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table name is SpecailUserrate contain these records

```
USER_ID    NAME   FromCountry  ToCountry  Rate 
----------------------------------------------    
1          xyz      null         null     0.75
1          xyz      1            null     0.80 
1          xyz      null         2        0.81
```

I need the SQL statement to return 1 record

```
example user 1 want to use special rate depend on FromCountry or ToCountry
```

if the user 1 from country 1 has special rate will use 0.80 
if not will use default rate 0.75

Any help ?

Comment: share what you have tried?

Comment: with what(variable ) are you trying to match FromCountry/ToCountry ?

Comment: explain the question more clearly, what does the user enter. what do you want to do with the user enterd value. Better use some example

Answer (score 0):

I dint get the question properly. But I guess the key to solution is using `EXISTS`.

Something that looks like this

```
 select * from country where FromCountry=1
 union
 select * from country where not exists(select * from where FromCountry=1) and ToCountry=2  
 union  
 select * from country where not exists(select * from where FromCountry=1 or ToCountry=2) and FromCountry is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of providing the answer:

```
select coalesce(c1.rate, def.rate) as rate
from 
    ( select user_id, rate 
      from Special_User_rate
      where fromcountry is null and tocountry is null) def
    left join 
        ( select user_id, rate
          from Special_User_rate
          where fromcountry = 1 ) c1
    on def.user_id = c1.user_id
/
```

It is not ideal because it's hard to inject a value for `fromcountry` into the sub-query.